# How to block scripts loading from certain domains?

Tags: configuration, noscript

On a few sites I visit using Tor, there are (apparently harmless) third-party scripts collecting user activity information for marketing purposes. These scripts are seriously slowing down the page load, and I'd like to block them from even having a chance to start loading.

AdBlock Plus would have been the solution, except the warnings about installing third-party extensions in Tor have me too concerned to do so. Is there a safe, *flexible* way to block certain resources on the page when loaded?

Comment: Not without compromising anonymity.